# Combining objects in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, element

I am working on a project with two other people located remotely. We are trying to bring our three objects together so when we run our web app it shows a rotating pinwheel, the blue outline of a square, and a red orbiting circle. Unfortunately, I can not tell if there is a small simple error in the syntax that I am overlooking, or if it is that our elements are not matching up. Any advice is welcome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<style>
  body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }
  #buttons {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 10px;
  }
  #buttons > input {
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 5px;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
  <div id="buttons">
    <input type="button" id="clear" value="Clear">
  </div>
  <script>
    (function() {

        function init() {
          var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
          var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
          var w = canvas.width;
          var h = canvas.height;

          var circle = function(color, r) {
            c.fillStyle = color;

            c.beginPath();
            c.arc(0, 0, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
            c.closePath();

            c.fill();
          }

          var i = 0;
          var redraw = function() {
            c.save();


            c.fillStyle = 'gray';
            c.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);


            c.translate(w / 2, h / 2);


            c.rect(10, 10, 100, 100);
            c.strokeStyle = 'blue';
            c.stroke();


            c.rotate(i / 200);
            c.translate(200, 0);


            circle('red', 10);

            c.restore();

            i++;

            c.translate(100, 100);
            var rotateAngle = 0.01;


            function draw(time) {

              c.clearRect(-100, -100 canvas.width, canvas.height);
              c.beginPath();
              c.fillStyle = "red";
              c.moveTo(100, 0);

              for (var angle = 0; angle < 2 * Math.PI; angle += 0.01) {
                var x = 100 * Math.cos(2 * angle) * Math.cos(angle);
                var y = 100 * Math.cos(2 * angle) * Math.sin(angle);
                c.lineTo(x, y);
              }

              c.fill();
              c.rotate(rotateAngle);
              requestAnimationFrame(redraw);
            };

            requestAnimationFrame(redraw);

            function speedUpdate(factor) {
              rotateAngle = factor * rotateAngle;
            }

          }
          window.addEventListener('load', init, false);

        }());
    }
  </script>
  </head>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. `<style>…</style>` needs to be inside the `<head></head>`, another `<title></title>` and `<meta charset="utf-8"/>` is missing in the `head`, there’s an excess closing `</head>` at the bottom.

Comment: I'm getting the error `missing ')' after argument list` when I run this.

Comment: A threw this into a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kwarrtz/j7wyqLfv/)

Comment: There’s a missing comma in `c.clearRect(-100, -100 canvas.width, canvas.height);`.

Comment: And the `}());` and `}` at the bottom are the wrong way around.

Comment: You are defining `function init(){}` and calling `init` with an event listener ___from within `init`___. Of course `init` cannot be called from inside a function that isn’t being called from outside. Move the event listener _outside_.

Comment: The same thing happens with `redraw`.

Comment: With [a bunch of errors corrected](http://jsfiddle.net/mLuxm0yo/), at least the contents of the canvas are visible. Now you can put your code in [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) and start correcting the warnings and errors shown there. `draw` and `speedUpdate` are never called, `time` is never used.

Comment: I was able to keep up pretty well right up until you mentioned the same thing happening with redraw Xufox. Do both requestAnimationFrame(redraw); need to come outside of init?

Comment: Never mind, I was able to figure it out! Thank you so much for your help Xufox and Kwarrtz, really appreciate it!

Comment: This question should be asked on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript

Comment: @RobG Nope, because the code doesn’t work.